# How to get the hashtag value and ampersand value of a url in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, query-string

I have a url like `http://www.example.com/folder/file.html#val=90&type="test"&set="none"&value="reset?setvalue=1&setvalue=45"`

Now I need to get the portion of url from starting from #, How do I get that, I tried using `window.location.search.substr();` but looks like that searches for ? in a url. is there a method to get the value of url after #

How do I also get  a portion of url from ampersand &

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte isnt there any shortcut way to get anything after ampersand like what we have for hash tag, if not then what is the approach

Comment: Have you tried the accepted approach in the link I gave at the bottom of my answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript That will parse the query string. If you were doing this server-side (e.g., PHP/Rails/etc.) it would be much simpler.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
```

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Update: This will grab all characters after the hashtag, including any query strings. From the  MOZ manual:

```
window.location.hash === the part of the URL that follows the # symbol, including the # symbol.
You can listen for the hashchange event to get notified of changes to the hash in
supporting browsers.
```

Now, if you need to PARSE the query string, which I believe you do, check this out here: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Is ther a way to get a value after &

Comment: That's a separate question - please post it as such, or edit the current question. The part after `?` (not `&` is the query string - you asked about the hash).

Comment: @Mike it grabs everything after the hash tag, including the hashtag and your query-string without the '?'. :)

Comment: Suppose I just have www.domain.com&val=1&val=4, and I need to get &val=1&val=4

Comment: what do I need to grab just the query string.

Comment: `.hash` does not grab the query string

Comment: @Utkanos Yes it will, in his case. It will grab all characters following the hash. Try it out.

Comment: `.hash` does not grab the query string - what the OP has is a contrived query string that is actually part of the hash. A real query string goes before the hash in a URL.

Comment: @Mike I hope you don't have a query string with identical keys like val and val. :) Check my updated answer. At the bottom there is a link on how to parse a query string in js.

Comment: @Utkanos I don't think we are arguing about anything here. I've made it clear that .hash will grab it in this particular case only. :)

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte - agreed :) Sorry - I just saw your comment where you said "including ... and your query string".

Answer (score 6):

To grab the hash:

```
location.hash.substr(1); //substr removes the leading #
```

To grab the query string

```
location.search.substr(1); //substr removes the leading ?
```

[EDIT - since you seem to have a sort query-string-esq string which is actually part of your hash, the following will retrieve and parse it into an object of name/value pairings.

```
var params_tmp = location.hash.substr(1).split('&'),
    params = {};
params_tmp.forEach(function(val) {
    var splitter = val.split('=');
    params[splitter[0]] = splitter[1];
});
console.log(params.set); //"none"
```

Comment: This is because you're confusing query strings with hashes. You seem to have a sort of query string-esq string as part of your hash. If you want to extract *that* you'll need some REGEX, string-handling. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To get the hash

```js
window.location.hash
```

To get the hash value (without `#`)

```js
window.location.hash.slice(1)
```