# Jquery - Get after '#' values from query string not after '?' symbol values

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string

I have a given below link,

***http://pathname/Home/Welcome?ID=69#tab2***

We can able to get the query string values(after *?* sysmbol) from the above link.. It is possible, But i want to get the after '*#*' symbol values(*tab2*) from the above url.

Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the hashtag value and ampersand value of a url in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727360/how-to-get-the-hashtag-value-and-ampersand-value-of-a-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 7):

You can get it with this variable:

```
window.location.hash
```

Want to know when it changes?

```
window.onhashchange = function(){
   // it changed!
};
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onhashchange

Comment: Good thinking on the `onhashchange` event, though support isn't full IIRC. There's a jquery onhashchange plugin.

Comment: @ManikandanSethuraju awesome. Please mark the answer as best as soon as you can do it :)

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.hash` and similar (`someAnchor.href.hash` etc).

A note on nomenclature. That isn't a query-string, the query string ends at the `#`, that's the fragment identifier.